# Hook a script as the very last one before the closing body tag

Tags: javascript, hooks, templates

I'm trying to add a script in the very last position before the closing  via function.php

Other scripts are hooked by other plugins, so WP is placing my script as the firts one of the list. Like:

[my script]
[the script generating the element I'd like to target]

Is there a way to tell Wordpress to hook my script as the last one before the closing  tag, no matter what the other scripts are doing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are scripts enqueued via `wp_enqueue_script()`, the absolute best solution would be to locate the registration/enqueuement of the script creating the element and simply specify it's handle as a dependency for your script. WordPress will then ensure that yours loads after that dependency.

There are other work-arounds to ensure that your script is the absolute last, but they're not really elegant or pragmatic. Ultimately, if the script which creates the element does not do so *immediately* as it loads (and it's fairly unlikely that it does, in my experience), then your script must both come after the script in question as well as hook into the same or a latter JS event.

If you're unable to ascertain a script hook which you can depend on, you might consider using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or equivalent jQuery functionality in order to simply execute your JavaScript whenever the element becomes available.

Without seeing any of your code or the code on which depends, it's not possible to suggest which route you should take.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. I'm still not an expert in WP scripts, but I'll make a try.
Thanks again!